# Multiple Languages Php

Tags: php, lang

I made a website in two languages (FR, NL) and it's working fine when I am in local.
When I uploaded the website the link to navigate between the both languages doesn't work and I don't know why..

Here are my links :

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="?lang=fr">FR -</a></li>
  <li><a href="?lang=nl">NL</a></li>
</ul>
```

and my config file :

```
<?php
if ($_GET['lang']=='fr') {          
  include('fr-lang.php');
} 
else if ($_GET['lang']=='nl') {      
  include('nl-lang.php');
}
else {                      
 include('fr-lang.php');
}
?>
```

This is the website : http://www.chjt.be/rapport-2019/
And when I click on languages links it's going on homepage : http://www.chjt.be/

What did I miss ?
Thank you =)

Comment: In php, `elseif` should be one word according to the PSR12 coding standard.  How about `include(($_GET['lang'] ?? 'fr') == 'nl' ? 'nl' : 'fr') . '-lang.php');` ...but your script looks correct as is.  Do you have a redirect in play that is killing the query string?

Comment: I don't think we can tell, given the code in your question. The page does a 302 redirect: "Moved Temporarily".

Comment: I guess there is an htaccess role which redirect the request to the main page and so the GETTER is removed

Comment: Oh I didn't think about that. I will check ! Thank you for your quick answers.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, I had to change the 'lang' code to an other name to make it work. There was a WordPress plugin who made it doesn't work.